# Ошибка в кодировке Mysql

Tags: mysql, кодировка, phpmyadmin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кодировка БД: utf-8
php: тоже utf-8

Comment: `php: тоже utf-8` - что это значит? файл? или соединение?

Comment: В чём-проблема-то? Ну да, выглядит как кракозябры. Но, может, это на самом деле не кракозябры, а действительно имя и фамилия у кого-то именно такие? Если вы уверены, что это не так, предоставьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) со всеми шагами от начала и до конца, которые привели к появлению такого результата. Сейчас ваши скриншоты ни о чём не говорят.

Comment: Скорее всего, в базе всё в порядке и правильно (только имейте в виду, что в MySQL `utf-8` это не UTF-8). Это что-то до базы успешно побило данные.

Comment: И файл и соединение — Utf-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего данные были в базу внесены в кодировке отличной от описанной utf-8, как и было указано ранее. Кодировка текстов файлов php не означает, что страница (например форма) принимает и отправляет данные в этой кодировке. Посмотрите в заголовке сформированной и отправленной в браузер страницы какая там указана кодировка. Переключите кодировку в браузере в котором видите эту страницу и есть шанс, что увидите данные крякозяблы в читаемом виде, хотя остальной текст вокруг станет не читаемым. Это и даст Вам подсказку.